# Haskell list comprehension challenge problem

Tags: haskell

I am now having two lists containing locations, list1 and list2

A function called generateDist which takes two location and generates distance from that two loctions

I am now aiming to generate number of elements in list1 that is just one unit away from a particular element in list2 (only pick the closest one)

My current expression is in below:

```
let l = [x|x <- list1, y <- list2, generateDist x y == 1]
```

This does not give me expected answer, since I also want elements that is just two units away from a particular one element in list2 (a location can be one unit away from location a, and two units away from location b, I only want the closest one being counted)

To make this more clear, If I have two lists:

```
list1 = [1,4,7] and list2 = [2,3,6]
number of elements that are 1 unit away should be: 3
number of elements that are 2 units away should be: 0 (instead of 2 if using my expression)
```

Can someone please help me?
How should I implement this feature

Comment: Can you add your `generateDist` functions?

Answer (score 0):

> I only want the closest one being counted

If you only want the closest one then you could perhaps use a function like `minimum`:

```
[ x | x <- list1, minimum [ generateDist x y | y <- list2 ] == 2 ]
```

This does require that the distance type you use (the result of `generateDist`) has an instance of the `Ord` type class. E.g. for integers and the absolute value of the difference as distance you have:

```
ghci> list1 = [1,4,7]
ghci> list2 = [2,3,6]
ghci> generateDist x y = abs (x - y)
ghci> [ x | x <- list1, minimum [ generateDist x y | y <- list2 ] == 1 ]
[1,4,7]
ghci> [ x | x <- list1, minimum [ generateDist x y | y <- list2 ] == 2 ]
[]
```

Comment: God damn that was really helpful!